# Stop UICollectionView From Scrolling and Make it Show All Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, storyboard

I have a collection view that is working fine when it has 10 or less items. Each row has 5 items so up to 10 it has two rows. However, when I have more than 10 items, it creates a 3rd row that is cut off and the collection view starts scrolling. When I try to disable scrolling, the collection view cuts off the last row. I want to ideally have a collection view that will keep expanding vertically no matter how many rows I have. Can anybody point me in the direction for making that happen?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

**1. For dynamic height updates**

You can add an observer for the contentSize of collectionView

```
   collectionView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: [.new,.old], context: nil)
```

Then you can override this method to check the contentSize changes in collectionView

```
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                               of object: Any?,
                               change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                               context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

         if let obj = object as? UICollectionView, obj == self.collectionView && keyPath == "contentSize" {
            if let oldVal = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.oldKey] as? CGSize, let newValue = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? CGSize,oldVal.height == newValue.height  {
                return
            }

            let contentHeight = self.collectionView.contentSize.height
            //You can update the height constraint or you can manually update the height of collection view. 

            self.heightConstraintCV.constant = contentHeight 
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            self.view.setNeedsLayout()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

**2. A little simple way would be to calculate height manually. if you are sure that each row will have 5 elements.**

```
height = (numberOfRows * heightOfEachRow)
```

**3. Set the contentSizeHeight directly as height of collectionView**

`height = collectionView.contentSize.height`

Comment: The collection view cells will be static once layed out, as in the user will never see it change, so I'm looking for a way to lay it out when the open the view. Will this work for that?

Comment: In that case you can just get the contensize directly, like collectionView.contentSize, instead of observing it. and then set the height as height of collectionView

Comment: Another way is, if you know the height if your cells, you can just calculate `(no. of cells) * height`